# Xcode crashes when trying to open .xcworkspace in React Native project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, crash

I have setup my Podfile using https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md / https://calsob.in/add-google-maps-and-map-kit-to-react-native-app-in-10-steps/, but when i try to open the .xcworkspace file in Xcode or via command line (`open customer_app_rn.xcworkspace`), it crashes.

Xcode version: `Version 10.0 beta 5 (10L221o)`

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.1
```

Below is the crash details:

```
Process:               Xcode [43639]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               10.0 (14320.2.4)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-14320002004000000~14
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [43639]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
PlugIn Identifier:       libswiftDispatch.dylib
PlugIn Version:          4.2 (1000.0.32.1)

Date/Time:             2018-10-16 17:16:50.177 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G2112)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     2.4.1 (15P6613)
Anonymous UUID:        7C69219B-5A08-2E4D-D2DF-42B5421F990E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       59ED1DD0-78D2-4328-8189-CE9658200631

Time Awake Since Boot: 140000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       130 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: IDEXCBuildService

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 10L221o
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEPlugins_XCBuildSupport/IDEPlugins-14315.2.4/XCBuildSupport/PIFGeneration/IDEPIFGenerationCategories.m:337
Details:  _castedResult should be an instance inheriting from DVTFilePath, but it is nil
Object:   <IDEWorkspace: 0x7f90ff3282a0>
Method:   -xcbuildIntermediatesPath
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f90f7d1a0a0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   
 
Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[IDEWorkspace(IDEPIFGenerationCategories) xcbuildIntermediatesPath] (in XCBuildSupport)
  4   IDEXCBuildServiceSession.init(service:for:) (in XCBuildSupport)
  5   closure #1 in IDEXCBuildService.serviceSession(for:) (in XCBuildSupport)
  6   partial apply for closure #1 in IDEXCBuildService.serviceSession(for:) (in XCBuildSupport)
  7   closure #1 in IDEXCBuildService.serviceSession(for:)partial apply (in XCBuildSupport)
  8   partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@owned IDEXCBuildServiceSession, @error @owned Error) (in XCBuildSupport)
  9   thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@owned IDEXCBuildServiceSession, @error @owned Error)partial apply (in XCBuildSupport)
 10   partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out A, @error @owned Error) (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 11   closure #1 in closure #1 in OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<A>(fn:execute:rescue:) (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 12   partial apply for closure #1 in OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<A>(fn:flags:execute:rescue:) (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 13   partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<A>(fn:execute:rescue:) (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 14   partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 15   thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> ()partial apply (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 16   thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 17   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 18   _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
 19   @nonobjc OS_dispatch_queue.sync(execute:) (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 20   partial apply for @nonobjc  (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 21   OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<A>(fn:execute:rescue:) (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 22   OS_dispatch_queue.sync<A>(execute:) (in libswiftDispatch.dylib)
 23   @objc IDEXCBuildService.serviceSession(for:) (in XCBuildSupport)
 24   -[IDEXCBuildSystemServiceProvider noteBlueprintProviderDidChange:inWorkspace:] (in XCBuildSupport)
 25   -[IDEWorkspace notifyBuildSystemServiceProviderThatBlueprintProviderDidChange:] (in IDEFoundation)
 26   -[Xcode3Project _projectDidChange:] (in DevToolsCore)
 27   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
 28   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 29   ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
 30   -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] (in CoreFoundation)
 31   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 32   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 33   -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in DVTFoundation)
 34   -[PBXProject didFinishChangingProject] (in DevToolsCore)
 35   -[PBXProject writeToFile:projectFile:userFile:outResultNotification:] (in DevToolsCore)
 36   -[PBXProject _writeToFileSystemProjectFile:userFile:checkNeedsRevert:] (in DevToolsCore)
 37   -[Xcode3Project writeToFilePath:forceWrite:error:] (in DevToolsCore)
 38   -[IDEContainer _saveContainerForAction:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 39   __NSFireTimer (in Foundation)
 40   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 41   __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 42   __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 43   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 44   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 45   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 46   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 47   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 48   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 49   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 50   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 51   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 52   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 53   main (in Xcode)
 54   start (in libdyld.dylib)
 
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
(_castedResult) != nil

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: IDEXCBuildService
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e7b66 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9b2080 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff5c7431ae abort + 127
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f8e94ee +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1324
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f8e9b1a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1256
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010dca748c _DVTAssertionHandler + 374
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010dca7765 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 374
7   com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000011ea42b88 -[IDEWorkspace(IDEPIFGenerationCategories) xcbuildIntermediatesPath] + 692
8   com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000011ea503e1 IDEXCBuildServiceSessionserviceinit(_:_:) + 2257
9   com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000011ea6764a $S17IDEXCBuildSupport0A7ServiceC14serviceSession3forAA0acE0CSo0acE6Client_p_tKFAGyKXEfU_ + 362
10  com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000011ea676f1 $S17IDEXCBuildSupport0A7ServiceC14serviceSession3forAA0acE0CSo0acE6Client_p_tKFAGyKXEfU_TA + 17
11  com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000011ea69409 $S17IDEXCBuildSupport0A7ServiceC14serviceSession3forAA0acE0CSo0acE6Client_p_tKFAGyKXEfU_TA.7 + 9
12  com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000011ea67804 $S17IDEXCBuildSupport0A14ServiceSessionCs5Error_pIgozo_ACsAD_pIegrzo_TRTA + 20
13  com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000011ea693f9 $S17IDEXCBuildSupport0A14ServiceSessionCs5Error_pIgozo_ACsAD_pIegrzo_TRTA.11 + 9
14  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110ecf01 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out A, @error @owned Error) + 17
15  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110e4632 closure #1 in closure #1 in OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<A>(fn:execute:rescue:) + 82
16  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110ecf6d partial apply for closure #1 in OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<A>(fn:flags:execute:rescue:) + 29
17  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110ecf40 partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<A>(fn:execute:rescue:) + 16
18  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110ecd01 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 17
19  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110edff9 thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> ()partial apply + 9
20  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110db92e thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 14
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c65ddb8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c6711e1 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
23  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110e4bfa @nonobjc OS_dispatch_queue.sync(execute:) + 154
24  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110e9bb0 partial apply for @nonobjc  + 16
25  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110e44db OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<A>(fn:execute:rescue:) + 267
26  libswiftDispatch.dylib          0x00000001110e4b2f OS_dispatch_queue.sync<A>(execute:) + 159
27  com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000011ea678d5 @objc IDEXCBuildServicefor(_:) + 181
28  com.apple.dt.IDE.XCBuildSupport 0x000000011ea49f0e -[IDEXCBuildSystemServiceProvider noteBlueprintProviderDidChange:inWorkspace:] + 88
29  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010eae669e -[IDEWorkspace notifyBuildSystemServiceProviderThatBlueprintProviderDidChange:] + 96
30  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000124685e48 -[Xcode3Project _projectDidChange:] + 72
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3478dedc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
32  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3478ddaa _CFXRegistrationPost + 458
33  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3478dae1 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 225
34  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3474b880 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1664
35  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3474a9b7 _CFXNotificationPost + 599
36  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff3685a8c7 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
37  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010dc52efd -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 361
38  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000012443d1ab -[PBXProject didFinishChangingProject] + 55
39  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001244290fc -[PBXProject writeToFile:projectFile:userFile:outResultNotification:] + 2637
40  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000012442941d -[PBXProject _writeToFileSystemProjectFile:userFile:checkNeedsRevert:] + 161
41  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000124685a90 -[Xcode3Project writeToFilePath:forceWrite:error:] + 149
42  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010eec5abd -[IDEContainer _saveContainerForAction:error:] + 904
43  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff368ec739 __NSFireTimer + 83
44  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34782014 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
45  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34781c87 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1095
46  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3478178a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 346
47  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778d5b __CFRunLoopRun + 2427
48  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778153 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
49  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff33a62d96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
50  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff33a62b06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
51  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff33a62884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
52  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff31d13a73 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
53  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff324a9e34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
54  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010e312b1e -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 385
55  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff31d08885 -[NSApplication run] + 764
56  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff31cd7a72 NSApplicationMain + 804
57  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010da1a63d main + 605
58  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff5c697015 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af20e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af20e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af20e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e828a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7de20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7dd724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34779785 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778ad7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778153 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff36874f26 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000124b9a646 +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 217
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff368831f8 __NSThread__start__ + 1197
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af661 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af50d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7de20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7dd724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34779785 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778ad7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778153 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff36874f26 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000124ba8841 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 1537
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff368831f8 __NSThread__start__ + 1197
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af661 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af50d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e7cf2 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff347b388b __CFSocketManager + 635
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af661 _pthread_body + 340
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af50d _pthread_start + 377
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7e7a16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9b0589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff5a5ebd43 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 93
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff383eeab5 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_until<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 117
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff383ee9a0 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait_until<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>, std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 96
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff383ee5c9 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 361
6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff383ee359 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 9
7   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff383ee698 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >(void*) + 40
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af661 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af50d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7de25e semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c66d94f _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c66594e _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 58
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c660e53 _dispatch_worker_thread + 251
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af661 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af50d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue: +[IDEExtension startLocatingExtensionsOfExtensionPoint:didStartExtensions:didStopExtensions:]_block_invoke_3
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7de246 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c66d893 _dispatch_sema4_wait + 16
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c662e69 _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 151
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010ecf3354 __93+[IDEExtension startLocatingExtensionsOfExtensionPoint:didStartExtensions:didStopExtensions:]_block_invoke.127 + 25
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010dcf4308 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 801
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c6655fa _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c65ddb8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c670e81 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c668733 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c65f9a9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff5c65f755 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af169 _pthread_wqthread + 1387
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebe9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 19:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7de20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7dd724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34779785 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778ad7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778153 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff31e50fc4 _NSEventThread + 184
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af661 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af50d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 20:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7de20a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c7dd724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34779785 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778ad7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff34778153 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff36874f26 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff36874dfe -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000012a91305f -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff368831f8 __NSThread__start__ + 1197
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af661 _pthread_body + 340
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9af50d _pthread_start + 377
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c9aebf9 thread_start + 13


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff94d3f380  rcx: 0x00007ffee21e2338  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffee21e2370  rsp: 0x00007ffee21e2338
   r8: 0x00007fff8e5dd8a0   r9: 0x000000010ff697d7  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x00007fff5ba72160  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x000000000000002d
  rip: 0x00007fff5c7e7b66  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff94d1c168
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x10da19000 -        0x10da1bfff  com.apple.dt.Xcode (10.0 - 14320.2.4) <2AF78085-4F86-3DD3-99F4-9626F3C8DAB4> /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x10da26000 -        0x10e014fff  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation
```

...

```
VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=837.5M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=837.5M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.3G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.3G(100%)
 
                                  VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                          SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                       =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework                 256K        3 
Activity Tracing                     256K        2 
CG backing stores                   1560K        4 
CG image                             588K       24 
CG raster data                       100K        9 
CoreAnimation                       3972K       46 
CoreGraphics                           8K        2 
CoreImage                            148K       21 
CoreServices                         224K        2 
CoreUI image data                   3592K       24 
CoreUI image file                    300K       11 
Dispatch continuations              24.0M        2 
Foundation                            12K        4 
JS JIT generated code                  8K        3 
JS JIT generated code (reserved)     1.0G        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                      8K        2 
MALLOC                             221.3M       62 
MALLOC guard page                     80K       18 
Memory Tag 242                        12K        2 
Memory Tag 251                        44K        2 
SQLite page cache                    128K        3 
STACK GUARD                         56.1M       23 
Stack                               18.7M       25 
VM_ALLOCATE                          116K       19 
WebKit Malloc                       1108K        4 
__DATA                              76.2M      631 
__FONT_DATA                            4K        2 
__LINKEDIT                         281.1M      327 
__TEXT                             557.4M      585 
__UNICODE                            560K        2 
libnetwork                          1152K        2 
mapped file                        150.7M       54 
shared memory                       2896K       18 
===========                       =======  ======= 
TOTAL                                2.4G     1907 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space       1.4G     1907 

Model: MacBookPro15,1, BootROM 15.16.6613.0.0,0, 6 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_IntelUHDGraphics630Item, Intel UHD Graphics 630, Built-In
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro560XItem, Radeon Pro 560X, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, Micron, 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, Micron, 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x7BF), wl0: Jun 24 2018 21:16:16 version 9.130.28.44.32.1.55 FWID 01-55577fa3
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: iBridge Bus
USB Device: iBridge DFR brightness
USB Device: iBridge Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: iBridge ALS
USB Device: iBridge FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: iBridge
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 28.10
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 28.10
```

Comment: Try with a non beta version of XCode.

Comment: will try when i get a chance

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Stable Version 10.0 (10A255) worked !!